# openssl commands in Java

Tags: java, openssl, sha1

I have to run this commands in my java aplication:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign file.pem -out output.sha1 input.txt 
openssl enc -base64 -in output.sha1 -out output2.b64 -A
```

Is the any library do help me running this codes in my java server?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I need to sign a string and i have an example with openssl but i have to do this in Java. It's possible?

Comment: @Vítor - *"I need to sign a string ... in Java"* - Yes, its possible. But do you want to *sign*, or do you want to *hash* and *encrypt*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your just trying to encrypt a string with SHA1 correct?  Java has packages for this already without having to use OpenSSL.

Take a look at the following function for example:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String x) throws Exception {
      java.security.MessageDigest digest = null;
      digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

      digest.reset();

      digest.update(x.getBytes("UTF-8"));

      return digest.digest();
 }
```

From this point, you can base64 encode it or whatever else you would like to do with the output.

--Edit including hashing with key

```
private String sha1(String s, String keyString) throws   UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(key);

    byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    return new String( Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

    }
```

Comment: The private key is not required in this process? thanks

Comment: @VítorNóbrega That is called HMAC.  I edited the answer to include an example of that.